# How to write a multiline Jinja statement

Tags: jinja2

I have an if statement in my Jinja templates which I want to write it in multines for readability reasons. Consider the case

```
{% if (foo == 'foo' or bar == 'bar') and (fooo == 'fooo' or baar == 'baar') etc.. %}
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

According to the documentation: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#line-statements you may use multi-line statements as long as the code has parens/brackets around it. Example:

```
{% if ( (foo == 'foo' or bar == 'bar') and 
        (fooo == 'fooo' or baar == 'baar') ) %}
    <li>some text</li>
{% endif %}
```

Edit: Using `line_statement_prefix = '#'`* the code would look like this:

```
# if ( (foo == 'foo' or bar == 'bar') and 
       (fooo == 'fooo' or baar == 'baar') )
    <li>some text</li>
# endif
```

*Here's an example of how you'd specify the `line_statement_prefix` in the [`Environment`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#jinja2.Environment):

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape
env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication', 'templates'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml']),
    line_statement_prefix='#'
)
```

Or using Flask:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True, static_folder='static')
app.jinja_env.filters['zip'] = zip
app.jinja_env.line_statement_prefix = '#'
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Pretty sure you'd get: `expected token 'end of statement block', got 'pass'` when running this. Similarly when replacing `pass` by a `set` or regular assignment, I think you'll get `expected token 'end of statement...`. Instead you'll have to wrap each statement in `{% %}` separately, e.g.: `{% if ... %} {% set x = 1 %} {% endif %}`.

Comment: I suppose you meant to place the  `%}` above `pass`, as you did with the `#` syntax.

Comment: @timdiels: a belated thank you for the comments. I corrected the examples and updated the links.