# Python: Multiple conditions for if statement in Jinja templates

Tags: python, jinja2

I got stuck in my coding project in jinja templates.

I want to show posts of a user just if 2 conditions are met:

The problematic part is if using `and`, conditions work perfectly individually but the moment I add `and` and join them together it does not work.

I have tried it with brackets and without them.

```
{% for post in posts %}

  {% if (session['user']['username']==post['author']) and (post["id"] | is_liked) %}

  {% else %}
    <li class="row">
      {% include "components/recommended.html" %}
    </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Could you please help me how to write that line, so that both conditions are checked?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168831/how-to-write-a-multiline-jinja-statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a multiline Jinja statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168831/how-to-write-a-multiline-jinja-statement)

Comment: I have seen this amswer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168831/how-to-write-a-multiline-jinja-statement . And I have tried it before, but it does not work. I have done this: {% if ( (session['user']['username']==post['author']) and
      (post["id"] | is_liked) )
%}                                         and I have tried this as well {% if ( (session['user']['username']==post['author']) and
      (post["id"] | is_liked) ) : pass
%}     The second one gives error becouse of pass, I have deleted it, run it just with brackets but it still does not consider my conditions.

Comment: @Viktória did you ever solve this issue? I'm having a similar problem where I want to assess multiple conditions in an if, but when I add brackets the template does not compile. If I remove the brackets then it works but I would like to keep the brackets for readability.

Comment: Unable to replicate this error, I tried this `{% if 1 == 1 and 3 ==2 %}
                  this works
        {% else %}
                  this doesn't work
        {% endif %} ` and it gave expected output, I would encourage you to check your condition

Answer (score 6):

Check this [nested ifs](https://overiq.com/flask-101/basics-of-jinja-template-language/#if-statement) (it suggests nested-ifs can be used how you would normally use them while writing native python code)
and [combining if conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15168895/14579276) (multi-line if statements can be used as long as the code has parens/brackets around it)

Both of them work well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

came across the same problem and my solution looks like this:

```
{%- set test1 = '00:00' -%}
{%- set test2 = '00:00' -%}
{%- set test3 = '00:00' -%}
{%- set allconditionsmet = 'no' %}
{%- if test1 == '00:00' -%}
{%-   if test2 == '00:00' -%}
{%-     if test3 == '00:00' -%}
{%-       set allconditionsmet = 'yes' %}
{%-     endif -%}
{%-   endif -%}
{%- endif -%}
{%- if allconditionsmet == 'yes' -%}
{{    'all conditions met' }}
{%- else -%}
{{    'some conditions not met' }}
{%- endif -%}
```

you could also use a bool or an int or whatever you like as the allconditionsmet.
maybe you make it an int and count up, then you can determine if 5 of 7 conditions are ok. whatever floats your goat.