# Shortening jinja if statements

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am creating a web app that allows users to create timelines (e.g. for worldbuilding or novels).

Within this, for a historical event the user can enter these 8 things: Start year/month/day/hour, and end year/month/day/hour, with only Start year being required.

The app inserts these into a database along with the rest of the entry details, into two columns: start date which contains the start y/m/d/h and end date which contains end y/m/d/h. These strings are formatted like so: `'Y:M:D:H'`. Sometimes they might be `'203:None:None:None'` or `'203:None:23rd:None'` etc.

I have come to displaying them within my web app with jinja, and so far the options I have to display them are very long and will just be a very large amount of `ifs`/`elifs`.

To show what I am aiming for, here is the first part of code I have:

*note: sy=start year, ey=end year, sm=start month, and so on and so forth. These are retrieved via `sy,sm,sd,sh=era_entries_dict[era][5].split(':')`. This code is within a for loop over a list of eras, and displays historical entries within eras.*

```
{% if (sm == 'None') and (sd=='None') and (sh=='None') %}
    {% if ey == 'None' %}
        <h6 class="text-muted">{{ sy }}</h6>
    {% else %}
        {% if (em=='None') and (ed=='None') and (eh=='None') %}
            <h6 class="text-muted">{{ sy }} > {{ ey }}</h6>
        {% elif (ed=='None') and (eh=='None') %}
            <p class="text-muted">{{ sy }} > {{ sm }} {{ sy }}</p>
```

So essentially, if its only the years on their own (`sy` or `sy` and `ey`) it will be in a h6 tag, else a paragraph tag.

Is there any way to do this shorter? I appreciate any tips/advice. Thanks!

Comment: There's no way to avoid that. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168831/how-to-write-a-multiline-jinja-statement Another way is to create a flag in your python controller, and pass the boolean flag as a variable to your jinja template.

Comment: If you started to think that you wrote too much template code, you know that it is time to refactor that logic into your views.